# After making some changes to my code, it no longer works on HEROKU but it works on local machine

Tags: python, heroku

I have a discord bot being hosted on heroku. It worked without a single problem before but after making some changes in the code itself it no longer starts up. It gives me an NameError: "datetime" not defined. I have not touched this part of my code when I was working on it.

```
import asyncio
import discord
import datetime
```

It has a problem right at the start of my file. With the import "datetime" line.

Here is the error code :

```
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691307+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691381+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "Main.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691448+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import discord
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691454+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/discord/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691558+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from .client import *
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691560+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/discord/client.py", line 36, in <module>
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691715+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from .user import User
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691724+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/discord/user.py", line 26, in <module>
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691836+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import discord.abc
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691839+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/discord/abc.py", line 101, in <module>
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691958+00:00 app[worker.1]:     SnowflakeTime = Union[Snowflake, datetime]
2021-05-11T18:09:00.691983+00:00 app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

Here is my procfile :

```
worker: python Main.py
```

And here is my requirements.txt

```
asyncio
datetime
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In requirements.txt delete the `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` and add `discord.py==1.7.2`

Comment: Hey, this seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks a lot. Changing the requirements.txt fixed it and now its running without a problem.